# Front end theme options ajax returns 0

Tags: ajax, theme-options

Can you anyone help me to get the front_end ajax returns response value as 1.i have updated the below code is now returning response value as 0

```
if (isset($_POST['frontliveeditor_settings']) && isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "fnrlvedt_updateoption"){
    if (wp_verify_nonce($_POST['frontendlvedt'],'frnendlv_updateoptions')){ 
        update_option('frontliveeditor_settings', $_POST['frontliveeditor_settings']);
    }
}

if(! function_exists( 'fend_clear_options' )):  
    function fend_clear_options(&$fend_value) {
       $fend_value = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes( $fend_value ));
    }
endif;



if(! function_exists( 'fend_save_settings' )):  
   function fend_save_settings ( $fend_data , $fend_rfresh = 0 ) {
       global $fend_arrayoptions;
       $fend_arrayoptions = array( 'frontliveeditor_settings' );
       foreach( $fend_arrayoptions as $fend_option ){
           if( isset( $fend_data[$fend_option] )){
               array_walk_recursive( $fend_data[$fend_option] , 'fend_clear_options');
               update_option( $fend_option ,  $fend_data[$fend_option] );
           }        
       }

       if( $fend_rfresh == 2 ) {    wp_die('2');}
       elseif( $fend_rfresh == 1 ){ wp_die('1');}
  }

endif;


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------*/
# Save Options
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------*/

add_action('wp_ajax_fnrlvedt_updateoption', 'fnrlvedt_updateoption');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fnrlvedt_updateoption', 'fnrlvedt_updateoption');

if(! function_exists( 'fnrlvedt_updateoption' )):   
function fnrlvedt_updateoption() {

    check_ajax_referer('fend-theme-data', 'security');
    $fend_data = $_POST;

    $fend_rfresh = 1;

    fend_save_settings ($fend_data , $fend_rfresh );
}
endif;

<form id="frontlvedtr_saveoptions" class="frontlvedtr_hiddenitems" name="frontlvedtr_saveoptions" action="" method="post">  
<div class="frontlvedtr_hdltad1">   
enter your name : <input class="lt1hd1adcontnum" type="text" size="9" id="lveditlefthdad1" name="frontliveeditor_settings[lveditlefthdad1]" value="<?php echo intval(get_lveditoption('lveditlefthdad1')); ?>" />
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="fnrlvedt_updateoption"/>
<input type="hidden" name="security" value="<?php echo wp_nonce_field('fend-theme-data'); ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="frnendlv_updateoptions" value="Save" class="lvedtsubmtbtn"/>

</form>


jQuery('form#frontlvedtr_saveoptions').submit(function() {

          var data = jQuery(this).serialize();

          jQuery.post(stchk.fedajaxurl, data, function(response) {
         alert(data);
         alert(response);
          if(response == 1) {

          jQuery('#savealert').addClass('savedone');
          t = setTimeout('fademessage()', 3000);

          }
          else if( response == 2 ){

          location.reload();
          }

          else {
              return false;
          }

          });
          return false;
      });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a bad action for your AJAX request, the action should match with your string next to `wp_ajax_`:

`add_action('wp_ajax_fend_theme_data_save', 'fend_theme_data_save');`, so your action HTML field should be like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="fend_theme_data_save" />
```

See the difference? Your action value should always be next to `wp_ajax_` or `wp_ajax_nopriv`, whatever you're using. I recommend you to read [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Also, if you're using `check_ajax_referer('fend-theme-data', 'security');` function, you should send the `security` parameter within your jQuery data with its respective value, read more about [this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_ajax_referer/); in this case will be something like this:

`security=your-nonce-string`.

**your-nonce-string** means that you need to create a nonce named `fend-theme-data` (the string that you're comparing with check_ajax_referer() function) and send it using `wp_localize_script()` function, read more about [this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/), and [this one](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/) to create the nonce.

And, do not use `die()` PHP function, use `wp_die()` or `wp_send_json_success` or `wp_send_json_error` WordPress default functions.

I hope my answer helps you. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65504/discussion-on-answer-by-roel-magdaleno-front-end-theme-options-ajax-returns-0).